# HTML code within textarea, buttons that pop up preview of the result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, textarea

I've gotten everything in my assignment to work except pretty much the main part. I can't figure out how to make my code read the contents of my textarea as HTML code and display the results in a new window. I can't even figure out how to display the contents as they appear.

I haven't kept an entire log of all the the different forums I have visited, but here are a couple of the last few I was checking out.

- [Open a new browser window/iframe and create new document from HTML in TEXTAREA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659076/open-a-new-browser-window-iframe-and-create-new-document-from-html-in-textarea)
- [Popup preview of textarea input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9243298/popup-preview-of-textarea-input)
- https://www.codingforums.com/javascript-programming/174810-previewing-textarea-popup.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>
      Wiki editor
    </title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1> Rachel </h1>
    <script>
      var previewOpen;
      function preview() {
        previewOpen = window.open("", "previewOpen", "width=500, height=600");
        previewOpen.document.body.innerHTML = "HTML"; // Get the value of text area and run HTML code
      }
      function closePreview() {
        previewOpen.close();
        // function to close the preview 
      }
    </script>
    <p>Type your HTML code below:</p>
    <textarea rows="20" cols="75">
</textarea>
    <!-- textarea for submittance of code to be read and written -->
    <br>
    <span><input id="preview" type="submit" value="Preview" onClick="preview()">
    <input id="closePreview" type="submit" value="Close Preview" onClick="closePreview()"></span> <!-- buttons with event handlers to read areatext and perform functions-->
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code line is assigning static "HTML" string values to your newly opened windows body.

```
previewOpen.document.body.innerHTML = "HTML"; // Get the value of text area and run HTML code
```

If you want to take the values of user input, you have to take the value of `textarea`.

for that you can do something like this.

1.First add **id** to your `textarea`.

```
<textarea id="userValues" rows="20" cols="75">
```

2.Then take the user values from `function preview()`.

```
 function preview() {
        previewOpen = window.open("", "previewOpen", "width=500, height=600");
        previewOpen.document.body.innerHTML = document.getElementById("userValues").value; // Get the value of text area and run HTML code
      }
```

[It will show like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyMRx.png)

cheers!!!

Comment: Yes!!!! This did it! I did so many combinations of trying to get my code to read the textarea but nothing would do it. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do would be to add an id to your text area:

```
<textarea id="myTextArea" rows="20" cols="75">
</textarea> <!-- textarea for submittance of code to be read and written-->
```

then in your previewOpen function, set the html:

```
previewOpen.document.body.innerHTML = document.getElementById("myTextArea").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost close. Instead of assigning static `"HTML"` string to the new opened window body. Assign the value of `textarea`.

```
var previewOpen;

function preview() {
    const val = document.querySelector('textarea').value;
    previewOpen = window.open("", "previewOpen", "width=500, height=600");
    previewOpen.document.body.innerHTML = val; // Get the value of text area and run HTML code
}

function closePreview() {
    previewOpen.close(); // function to close the preview 
}
```